# Load script by nashorn not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, nashorn, isomorphic

I set the view config of spring boot app as:

```
@Configuration
public class ViewConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String[] SCRIPTS = {
            "nashorn/ejs.min.js",
            "nashorn/polyfill.js",
            "nashorn/render.js"
    };

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ScriptTemplateViewResolver viewResolver = new ScriptTemplateViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".ejs");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ScriptTemplateConfigurer viewConfigurer() {
        ScriptTemplateConfigurer configurer = new ScriptTemplateConfigurer();
        configurer.setEngineName("nashorn");
        configurer.setScripts(SCRIPTS);
        configurer.setRenderFunction("render");
        configurer.setSharedEngine(false);

        return configurer;
    }
}
```

and my maven structure as:

```
App
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
        |-- java
        |   `-- config
        |             `-- ViewConfig.java
        |   `-- Application.java
        |-- resources
        |   `-- nashorn
        |       `-- ejs.min.js
        |       `-- polyfill.js
        |       `-- render.js
        |   `-- templates
        |       `-- index.ejs
```

However, when I run with command `mvn spring-boot:run` I got to a problem failed to load script with root cause:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource [nashorn/ejs.min.js] not found`

My purpose is that I want to build a isomorphic app with Java and ReactJs but I got to these problems one week ago and until now I cannot solve these problem.

Comment: Out of interest, copy the "nashorn" folder to under the "templates" folder, I suspect it might be using the view resolver looking for things like `templates/nashorn/...js.ejs`, but I may be wrong...

Comment: One way you can try to troubleshoot is to add `new ClassPathResource("nashorn/ejs.min.js").getPath()` to your `main()` verify that spring is actually able to find this file in classpath

Comment: @BretC: I tried your way but the problem is still there. :)

Comment: Ok, was just a stab in the dark really...Sorry for wasting any time!